# shows different screen on multiple device width responsiveness error

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html,body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .main-container-pg{
                color: #fff;
            }
            .main-container-pg:before{
                content: '';
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                left: 0;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;
                background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/c1cKTkc/bg-mid.png');
                background-size: 104% 100% ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: -1;
            }

            .logo-box-pg{
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .logo-head-pg{
                height: calc(100% - 82%);
            }

            .main-text-pg{
                display: flex;
                font-size: 1.4em;
                margin: auto;
                justify-content: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                padding-top: 1em;
            }
            .input-pg-box{
                padding-top: 3em;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                
            }

            .input-pg-box *{
                font-size: 1em;
            }
            .input-pg-box .pg-button-icon{
                background-color:  #6BB9E6;
                border: none;
                width: 10.625em;
                border-radius: 30px;
                margin-left: 1em;
                height: 3.5em;
                outline: none;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-around;
                padding-left: 1em;
                padding-right: 1em;

            }
            .drop-shadow{
                filter: drop-shadow(10px 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));   
            }
            .input-email-pg{
                width: 25%;
                height: 3.5em;
                outline: none;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 30px;
                color: #6BB9E6;
                padding-left: 10px;
            }
            .text-width{
                width: calc(10.625em + 22%);
            }


            /* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
            @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .input-email-pg{
                    background-color: red;
                }
            }

            /* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
                .input-email-pg{
                    background-color: green;
                }
            }

            /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
                .input-email-pg{
                    background-color: blue;
                }

                /*
                    1. Logo Position 
                    2. Text Position 
                    3. input Field Postition
                */
            }

            /* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
                .input-email-pg{
                    background-color: orange;
                }

                .main-container-pg:before{
                        background-size: 134% 100%;                     
                }
            }

            /* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
            @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
                .input-email-pg{
                    background-color: black;
                }
                .main-container-pg:before{
                        background-size: 104% 100%;                     
                }
            }
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-container-pg">
            <div class="logo-box-pg">
                <img src="logo.png" class="logo-head-pg">
            </div>

            <div class="main-text-pg">
                    <div class="text-width">
                        <h2 class="">
                            Partyguru sta arrivando per <br /> rivoluzionare il mondo degli<br />eventi privati
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-width">
                        <h2>
                            Vuoi saperne di più? <br />Iscriviti alla nostra newsletter
                        </h2>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-pg-box">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Indirizzo E-mail" class="input-email-pg drop-shadow"/>
                <button class="pg-button-icon drop-shadow">
                    <svg width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 34 34" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path
                            d="M19.3942 22.005C19.1356 22.8099 18.9371 23.6328 18.8002 24.467C18.3922 26.533 17.9462 28.858 16.0792 30.726C15.2055 31.6005 14.1681 32.2942 13.0262 32.7675C11.8843 33.2409 10.6603 33.4845 9.42416 33.4845C8.18804 33.4845 6.96405 33.2409 5.82214 32.7675C4.68023 32.2942 3.6428 31.6005 2.76916 30.726C1.61617 29.5948 0.785058 28.1771 0.36117 26.6184C-0.062717 25.0598 -0.064092 23.4164 0.357173 21.857C0.777483 20.253 1.61619 18.7893 2.78756 17.6157C3.95894 16.442 5.42095 15.6004 7.02416 15.177L8.12417 19.209C7.22959 19.4445 6.41356 19.9132 5.75946 20.5673C5.10535 21.2214 4.63663 22.0374 4.40118 22.932C4.16711 23.7853 4.16795 24.686 4.40365 25.5388C4.63935 26.3917 5.10113 27.165 5.74017 27.777C6.22562 28.2637 6.80231 28.6498 7.43722 28.9133C8.07213 29.1767 8.75278 29.3123 9.44018 29.3123C10.1276 29.3123 10.8082 29.1767 11.4431 28.9133C12.078 28.6498 12.6547 28.2637 13.1402 27.777C14.0922 26.825 14.3772 25.365 14.7112 23.67C14.8352 23.027 14.9712 22.359 15.1442 21.691L19.3942 22.005Z"
                            fill="white" />
                        <path
                            d="M8.11506 19.1999C8.64706 19.0519 9.21506 18.9399 9.82206 18.8169C11.8881 18.3959 14.2221 17.9169 16.0691 16.0709C17.3851 14.7545 18.2813 13.0775 18.6443 11.2518C19.0074 9.42609 18.821 7.53375 18.1087 5.814C17.3964 4.09424 16.1902 2.62428 14.6426 1.58994C13.095 0.555595 11.2755 0.00332359 9.41407 0.00292969C9.27808 0.00292969 9.15408 0.0149236 9.01408 0.0279236C6.57833 0.12419 4.27553 1.16411 2.59272 2.92772C0.909922 4.69133 -0.0209178 7.04033 -0.00291755 9.47792C0.0103367 11.4978 0.676868 13.4592 1.89708 15.0689C2.99775 14.1597 4.25544 13.4595 5.60807 13.0029C4.92803 12.2867 4.46526 11.3921 4.2736 10.4232C4.08194 9.45431 4.16927 8.45092 4.5254 7.52969C4.88153 6.60847 5.49184 5.80725 6.28538 5.21922C7.07892 4.63119 8.02307 4.28051 9.00807 4.20793C9.14407 4.19593 9.26806 4.18292 9.40806 4.18292C10.0956 4.18093 10.7768 4.31551 11.4119 4.57884C12.0471 4.84217 12.6236 5.22903 13.1081 5.71693C14.0884 6.7006 14.6388 8.03271 14.6388 9.42143C14.6388 10.8102 14.0884 12.1423 13.1081 13.1259C12.1551 14.0779 10.6841 14.3749 8.97706 14.7339C8.33406 14.8699 7.67708 14.9939 7.02308 15.1789L8.11506 19.1999Z"
                            fill="white" />
                        <path
                            d="M30.7261 17.416C28.9608 15.6516 26.567 14.6604 24.0711 14.6604C21.5752 14.6604 19.1815 15.6516 17.4161 17.416C16.2809 18.6034 15.4936 20.0797 15.1401 21.684L19.4081 22.006C19.6067 21.3951 19.9407 20.8369 20.3851 20.373C21.3688 19.3927 22.7009 18.8423 24.0896 18.8423C25.4784 18.8423 26.8105 19.3927 27.7941 20.373C28.2807 20.8556 28.6668 21.4298 28.9301 22.0625C29.1934 22.6951 29.3286 23.3737 29.3281 24.059V24.071C29.3333 25.0876 29.0409 26.0835 28.4867 26.9359C27.9326 27.7882 27.1411 28.4597 26.2098 28.8675C25.2785 29.2753 24.2483 29.4015 23.2461 29.2307C22.2439 29.0598 21.3137 28.5993 20.5701 27.906C20.1569 29.2759 19.4896 30.5558 18.6031 31.679C20.1957 32.8473 22.12 33.4759 24.0951 33.473H24.1201C26.6119 33.4651 28.9989 32.47 30.7585 30.7057C32.5181 28.9414 33.5068 26.5518 33.5081 24.06V24.048C33.4939 21.5569 32.4932 19.1729 30.7251 17.418"
                            fill="white" />
                        <path
                            d="M23.045 0.0249023H18.876C18.8813 3.89756 20.422 7.6101 23.1604 10.3485C25.8988 13.0869 29.6113 14.6276 33.484 14.6329V10.4649C30.7153 10.4644 28.0601 9.36429 26.1024 7.40652C24.1446 5.44876 23.0445 2.7936 23.044 0.0249023"
                            fill="white" />
                    </svg>

                    <span style="color: #fff;"> iscriviti </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I already use media query in this design but not working with my code
When I am testing this on multiple devices then its shows different results please help me to make it responsive
when width of screen is changed then the buttons color will change help me to resolve this
I am new to web designing please help me to resolve this

Comment: Please explain beter what do you mean with _its shows different results_... and explain your desired result

Comment: Please refer standard sizes of media queries. Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: @Sfili_81  the size of background image remains same while changing the screen width

Comment: Try to Change ``background-size: 104% 100%;`` to ``cover``

Comment: Try also using `vw` and `vh` instead of `%` if you want your elements and images to be responsive with screen size.